# Find n words starting with capital letter before 2 words of capital letters (regex)

Tags: python, regex

I have written this regex but this is not working as expected.

```
((?:[A-Z][\w]+)?),[\s]([A-Z]{2})
```

Following are sample inputs.

```
Fort Worth, TX
This is Forth Worth, TX
We are looking for someone from Columbus, MS.
```

I expect City and State out of above string samples with regex in python but this is just no working as expected.

```
print re.findall('((?:[A-Z][\w]+){1,2}),[\s]([A-Z]{2})', input)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The space in between the city names.

Comment: You may want to use some sort of natural language parsing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add a white space character in your city name group, like this:

```
re.findall('((?:[A-Z][\w]+\s*){1,2}),[\s]([A-Z]{2})', input)
```

This will match a capital Latin letter followed by one or more word characters and zero or more white space characters, all of which may be appear one or two times, captured in group 1, followed by a comma, a white space character, and two capital Latin letters, captured in group 2.

Comment: Works and your answer didn't break my other rules so answer goes to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
([A-Z][^,]+),\s([A-Z]{2})
```

Or if you can only have word characters and spaces in the city name then:

```
([A-Z][\w\s]+),\s([A-Z]{2})
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sZ5wP5)

Comment: Second regex will bring whole text "We are looking for someone from Columbus, MS." won't it?

Comment: @UmairAshraf Yes it does, but how can you be sure that the city name isn't more than 2 words ? anyway your problem seems to be solved.

Comment: I have seen complete set of data to which this regex will be applied so yes I am sure why city max at 2 words.